# How to process one request at a time on the same TCP connection (Channel)?

Tags: netty

We have a Netty server using `NioServerSocketChannel` and `HttpServerCodec`. We have observed a bad client sending multiple requests on the same TCP connection (same Channel & ChannelPipeline) without waiting for a response. This bad client can be recreated using Netty client and doing multiple `ctx.write()`s with a `ctx.flush()` at the very end to send all the requests at once.

The result is Netty processes the requests at the same time in the same pipeline. Is there any way to have Netty process the requests one-at-a-time, waiting for a response to be sent back or some failure condition before trying to process the next request? Or will this require custom logic on our end to implement this?

We have Channel attributes set per request and the pipeline also changes depending on the request, so we cannot handle multiple requests at the same time on the same Channel.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a full duplex protocol, so it is completely legal to send multiple HTTP requests without waiting for a response. This approach is called HTTP pipelining. This is the reason netty does not disallow this by default.

If you can only process one request on a connection, then you will have to add a handler that rejects subsequent requests.